# Angular ternary in html with nullchecks

Tags: angular

I have the following code in my html

```
*ngIf="listing.sales?.last30days?.units && listing.sales.last30days.units > 0"
```

[image]

in the screenshot you can see the the Angular language is complaining. How can i write this ?

Comment: The screenshot shows your IDE 'complaining', not the "Angular language". Angular would complain via an error message in a compiler or browser console.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to collapse that more complex query into a getter in your code:

```js
get hasLast30Days() {
  return listing.sales?.last30days?.units && listing.sales.last30days?.units > 0
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="hasLast30Days">
    <p 
        class="mono" 
        [attr.data-tooltip]="'Last 30 Days Sales'"
        data-placement="top"
    >
        <span class="mr-2 text-lighten-1">S</span>
        <span>{{listing.sales?.last30days?.units}}</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I like the other way better

Answer (score -1):

One way is to use ng-container

```
<ng-container *ngIf="listing.sales?.last30days as sales">
    <p 
        class="mono" 
        [attr.data-tooltip]="'Last 30 Days Sales'"
        data-placement="top"
        *ngIf="sales.units > 0"
    >
        <span class="mr-2 text-lighten-1">S</span>
        <span>{{listing.sales?.last30days?.units}}</span>
    </p>
</ng-container>
```